# Any equivalent for DBC.TABLES and DBC.COLUMNS of Teradata in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, teradata

In Teradata we right now have a query which gives the list of table names and column names for specific databases like:

```
select * from dbc.tables where databasename in ('A','B','C')
```

Is there an equivalent for this Snowflake?

Comment: Snowflake supports Standard SQL Information Schema, should be `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` and `COLUMNS`

Answer (score 1):

INFORMATION_SCHEMA is under each database, if you want to get tables across multiple databases, then you can use

ACCOUNT_USAGE.TABLES
ACCOUNT_USAGE.COLUMS

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/tables.html
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/columns.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES and COLUMNS views which will display table and column information.

Please review the below documentation for more information.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema.html#information-schema-views-and-table-functions

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html#account-usage-views

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html#differences-between-account-usage-and-information-schema

Comment: But the tables for specific databases are not fetched. I will have to give individual databases like Select * from A.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;    What if I want to get all the tables used in 2 databases say A and B?

Answer (score 0):

The closest equivalent of:

```
select * from dbc.tables where databasename in ('A','B','C')
```

is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.COLUMNS
WHERE DELETED IS NULL
  AND TABLE_CATALOG IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

Account_usage contains dropped objects so to get only current one filter condition `DELETED IS NULL`  was added.

It is also worth noting that [ACCOUNT_USAGE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html#account-usage-views) views have latency (for columns and tables up to 90 minutes).